# Mocha Node Test, return result passing as Null instead of query value?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

so I'm trying to do a Mocha test here, but my return value (right before the .then) is coming in as  Null.

When I console log the Store.findById(resStore.id) I get the value in the log, but when I return it and pass it to then then, it shows Null?

```
       it('should return posts with right fields', function() {
  let resStore;
  return chai.request(app)
    .get('/stores')
    .then(function(res) {
      expect(res).to.have.status(200);
      expect(res).to.be.json;
      expect(res.body).to.be.a('array');
      expect(res.body).to.have.lengthOf.at.least(1);
      res.body.forEach(function(store) {
        expect(store).to.be.a('object');
        expect(store).to.include.keys('_id', 'name', 'storeLogo');
      });
      resStore = res.body[0];
      console.log(Store.findById(resStore.id)); // Response is QUERY Result
      return Store.findById(resStore.id);
    })
    .then(doc => {
      console.log(`Casey ${doc}`); //Response is Casey Null
      resStore.name.should.equal(doc.name);
      resStore.name.should.equal(doc.storeLogo);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I would expect `Store.findById` to return a Promise, not a query result. If it returns the latter, it would suggest that the method is synchronous.

Comment: I don't think query is the right word, but it returns results, not null.

ie:  Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  mongooseCollection:
   NativeCollection {
     collection: Collection { s: [Object] },
     opts:
      { bufferCommands: true,
        capped: false,
        '$wasForceClosed': undefined },
     name: 'stores',
     collectionName: 'stores',
     conn:
      NativeConnection {   ......

Comment: That's a Mongoose query object. It doesn't represent a query _result_, just a query. The query you're trying to run apparently yields no result.

Comment: I guess, I don't understand how I can log it on the line right above it, but when I return it, it's null?

Answer (score 1):

`Store.findById(resStore.id)` returns a [Mongoose `Query` object](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#Query), which represents a query. So that's what you see when you run `console.log` on it (the internal representation of that object).

When you return it *inside a Promise chain*, which is what you do, that `Query` object is regarded as being a Promise (it isn't a pure Promise, but it contains just the right amount of information to be treated as one), and will be waited for until it settles (until it either resolves or gets rejected). The result of that will be the actual result of the query, and that is what's being passed along to the last `.then` block (as `doc`).

How Promise chains work is documented here: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining#returning-promises